# How can I use a javascript promise to make one function wait for another to finish running asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

```
// TODO: FIX CODE - IT IS STILL NOT WAITING FOR populateVenueIDs
// BEFORE CALLING populateFsPhotoRequestURLs
// must use async, not sync to meet assignment requirements.

let populateVenueIDs = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  for (let y = 0; y < window.coffeeShopLocations().length; y++) {
    let getVenueIDFromFS = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getVenueIDFromFS.open('GET', window.fsURL[y]);
    getVenueIDFromFS.onload = function() {
      let responseFromFS = JSON.parse(getVenueIDFromFS.responseText);
      window.fsVenueID[y] = responseFromFS.response.venues[0].id;
      console.log(window.fsVenueID[y]);
    }; 
    getVenueIDFromFS.send();
  } 
  resolve("done!");
}); 

function populateFsPhotoRequestURLs() {
  for (let y = 0; y < window.coffeeShopLocations().length; y++) {
    window.fsPhotoEndpoint[y] = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'
      + window.fsVenueID[y] + '/photos';
    window.fsPhotoRequestURL[y] = fsPhotoEndpoint + '?' + fsPhotoParams;
    console.log(window.fsPhotoRequestURL[y]);
  } 
} 


populateVenueIDs.then(
  populateFsPhotoRequestURLs()
);
```

It is still not waiting for populateVenueIDs before running populateFsPotoRequestURLs.

I have also tried variants of await, promise, and then. I have read about 15 tutorials about those topics, but none are close enough to do what I want. I don't want to use a timeout (which 90% of tutorials use) because that would unnecessarily slow down the application. I have to use async to meet the assignment requirements. 
Please help me connect the dots to apply a promise and/or await/then that will apply in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `populateVenueIDs` function just resolves to done without waiting for the `onload` functions to be called. If you can, `fetch` would be a nice alternative because it returns promises but that isn't supported in IE.

What you can do, is create a promise for each iteration of your loop and use `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)` to wait for all requests. This will even execute all `XMLHttpRequest` in parallel!

Example code:

```
let populateVenueIDs = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let promises = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < window.coffeeShopLocations().length; y++) {
        promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve) {
            let getVenueIDFromFS = new XMLHttpRequest();
            getVenueIDFromFS.open('GET', window.fsURL[y]);
            getVenueIDFromFS.onload = function() {
                let responseFromFS = JSON.parse(getVenueIDFromFS.responseText);
                window.fsVenueID[y] = responseFromFS.response.venues[0].id;
                console.log(window.fsVenueID[y]);
                resolve();
            };
            getVenueIDFromFS.send();
        }));

    }
    return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function () {
            resolve('Done!');
        })
});
```

## Fetch Solution

As you've said this is an assignment, you probably can use ES6 with `async` and `await` so this would be a fancy solution:

```
async function populateVenueIDs() {

    let promises = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < window.coffeeShopLocations().length; y++) {
        promises.push(new Promise(async resolve => {
            const response = await fetch(window.fsURL[y]);
            const data = await response.json();
            window.fsVenueID[y] = data.venues[0].id;
            resolve();
        }));
    }

    await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct and I am only commenting because I wanted to emphasize that you should really really try to use fetch, or if you can't use fetch, some other ajax library, because vanilla XMLHttpRequest is really really painful to work with. Github also offers a fetch polyfill for older browsers if you're able to add libraries to your project: https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: @JensV Thank you very much. After trying the first solution above it still performed out of order, but that got me 99% where I need. I'll paste my final solution below. I will also be looking into switching to fetch.

Comment: ```return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function () {
      resolve('Done!');
      populateFsPhotoRequestURLs();
    })
});
populateVenueIDs;```

Answer (score 1):

While I feel strongly that @JensV had the right answer, and I said so in my comment, I just wanted to follow up on what your code might look like if you used fetch (I only included the relevant piece of JensV's answer.

```
var promises = [];

for (let y = 0; y < window.coffeeShopLocations().length; y++) {
    promises.push(fetch(window.fsURL[y])
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        window.fsVenueID[y] = data.response.venues[0].id;
      }));
}
```

EDIT: For posterity's sake I posted this before Jens added his fetch solution :)